# JUnit 5 and Arguments.of() with functions

Tags: junit5, parameterized

Writing a JUnit 5 parameterized test and need to pass functions to the test using Arguments.of(), but there are 2 compile errors that I don't know how to fix. Any help would be appreciated.

1. The method of(Object...) in the type Arguments is not applicable for the arguments (boolean, String::length)
2. The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

```
public static Stream<Arguments> some() {
    return Stream.of(Arguments.of(true, String::length));
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource
public <T> void some(final T input, final Function<String, Integer> length) {
}
```

The following works as expected.

```
public void sample() {
    some(true, String::length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I liked @adrian-redgers solution, but I think overloading a method for each signature needed is a bit overkill.

You only really need to convert the functional interface to an object. So the solution I implemented was:

```java
/**
 * Helps to use {@link org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments#of(Object...)}, as functional
 * interfaces cannot be converted into an object directly.
 */
public class ArgumentsWrapper {

    private ArgumentsWrapper() {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                ArgumentsWrapper.class + " util class cannot be instantiated");
    }

    public static <T, U> Function<T, U> wrap(Function<T, U> function) {
        return function;
    }
}
```

Then, it can be used as:

```java
 public static Stream<Arguments> testMapAlarmTypeConfigWithLanguage() {
    return Stream.of(
        // Statically imported ArgumentsWrapper#wrap
        Arguments.of(null, wrap(AlarmTypeConfig::getNameInEnglish)),
        Arguments.of("en-us", wrap(AlarmTypeConfig::getNameInEnglish)),
        Arguments.of("es-es", wrap(AlarmTypeConfig::getNameInSpanish)));
}
```

Comment: Nice! Best answer IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

I like @Miguel Alorda's solution of the wrapper function, however what also works is casting to the right type:

`Arguments.of((Function<String,Integer>) String::length)`

Or with an inline lambda such as this no-argument lambda:

`Arguments.of((Supplier<String>) ()-> "Supply World")`

BTW: You don't actually need the return-type, but you do need the type of the operand of the `Function<T,R>` otherwise the compiler cannot determine th method-reference to the `length()` function.

So the following compiles:

`Arguments.of((Function<String,?>) String::length)`

But this doesn't:

`Arguments.of((Function<?,?>) String::length)`

Answer (score 1):

**Wrap the arguments in a helper method**
Similar to the answer "wrap it in a class", but possibly less intrusive, is to use a helper method to pass the functional interface as a `java.lang.Object`.

For example, the first raw method reference, `Math::ciel`, in this parameterized test:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("testCases")
void shouldExerciseMethod(Function<Double, Double> method, Double expected) {
    assertEquals(expected, method.apply(1.5d), 1.0E-8d);
}
    
static Stream<Arguments> testCases() {
    return Stream.of(Arguments.of(Math::ceil, 2.0d),
                     Arguments.of(Math::floor, 1.0d));
}
```

causes this compilation error:

```
java: method of in interface org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.Object[]
  found: Math::ceil,double
  reason: varargs mismatch; java.lang.Object is not a functional interface
```

which you can get around by passing the arguments through a helper method:

```
static <T, U> Arguments args(Function<T, U> method, U expected) {
    return Arguments.of(method, expected);
}
```

so:

```
static Stream<Arguments> testCases() {
    return Stream.of(args(Math::ceil, 2.0d), 
                     args(Math::floor, 1.0d));
}
```

My attempts to make the idiom more general using `varargs` failed with variations on the same error, so I have ended up overloading it whenever I need another signature.

Comment: This works but can get cumbersome adding helper functions. I like the solution of wrapper-functions posted by @miguel alorda better: just wrap the one argument in a function of the proper type.

And you can also cast that one argument so it's type (be that Function, Supplier, or whatever) without the need for any wrapper functions at all, although the code probably looks a bit tidier when using a wrapper function.

Answer (score -1):

The function needs to be wrapped in a class.

```
public static class P {

    private final Function<String, Integer> mFunction;

    public P(final Function<String, Integer> function) {
        mFunction = function;
    }

    public Function<String, Integer> function() {
        return mFunction;
    }
}

public static Stream<Arguments> some() {
    return Stream.of(Arguments.of(3, "abc", new P(String::length)));
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource
public <T> void some(final int expect, final String input, final P p) {
    assertEquals(expect, p.function().apply(input));
}
```

Comment: While that works I think it's also the most cumbersome solution; casting the function to one of functional-interface types or wrapping it with a function that has one of functional interface types as parameter and return-type is probably easier and with less overhead.